# How to dynamically instantiate 3 different classes into the same variable name, linq2sql c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Say I have 3 tables in my database: people, tasks and projects

Say I have 3 classes for repository's: PeopleRepository, TaskRepository and ProjectRepository.

Now I want a single method, that will work with any of these classes.

Obviously I could just write out loads of code for each table, but I'd rather keep code down to a minimum. I already have reflection working fine for the different column names that might be passed to the method, but I can't seem to get code like this to work.

```
switch (tableName)
            {

                case "people":
                    var repository = new PeopleRepository();
                    break;
                case "tasks":
                    var repository = new TaskRepository();
                    break;
                case "projects":
                    var repository = new ProjectRepository();
                    break;
             }

//Modify respective database table
repository.getItem(id); //etc
repository.Save(); //etc
```

I've tried a few other things like this, but none of them seemed to work. Changing the scope of where the variable is defined etc.

I feel like c# should have something nice to deal with this, is this so? Or do I have to write the same code in each switch statement?

Comment: I do know the above code is obviously not going to work due to defining the same variable in the same scope, but it should show what I am trying to do.

Comment: If the code was possible, what would you do with it? I mean, why do you need to do this? What do you intend to do with the repository once you have it?

Comment: why can't you just define an interface for that?

Comment: It would mean that I could have a single method that will work upon multiple tables, I'm trying to make an ultra lightweight javascript crud tool for asp.net mvc autogenerated list views. This is to add crud to those views quickly, without much code. I want to keep the amount of code that has to be modified when adding a new table to a minimum. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an interface that those classes would implement. Then use

```
IRepository repository;

// your switch here
//switch() { case x: repository = new TypeRepository(); }

repository.GetItem(id);
repository.Save();
```

You can also make repository `dynamic`

```
dynamic repository;
```

And the type will be resolved in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent class (RepositoryBase) with virtual methods for .getItem(id) and .Save(), inherit from it, and override those methods in each implementation for PeopleRepository, TaskRepository, and ProjectRespository.

The other option is to create an interface (IRepository) that all three can use.